# LineString width with thin stroke

Tags: styles, stroke

I'm trying to draw a linestring like this:
[thin stroke but high internal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTvEw.png)

Any ideas? I've to use some complex style function?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you need. If you want to use it as a divider you could use the `<hr>` tag. But if you just want the box you could use a `<div></div>` with the following css.

```
div {
  width: 300px;
  border-top: 15px solid red;
  border-bottom: 15px solid red;
  background: grey;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```